Go module publishing: tag is posted on Github but the Go toolchain does not see it
I have a tool written in Go that I publish on Github with periodic revisions. The toolchain version is 1.23 and when I am ready to release a new version, I tag it in Git as vX.Y.Z and push to Github, after which one can install it using go install command:
go install github.com/abelikoff/vidsim@latest

Up until now, I was publsihing 1.X.Y versions and everything worked as expected. Recently, I bumped the version to 2, tagging my tool with v2.0.0 tag and so on. However since that time, I am not able to install the most recent version. Instead the last v1 version is always installed.
When I check the Github page for the tool, I clearly see the new v2 tags on Github. However, according to the Go toolchain, ony v1 tags are available:
$ go list -m -versions  github.com/abelikoff/vidsim
github.com/abelikoff/vidsim v1.0.0 v1.1.0 v1.1.1 v1.1.2 v1.2.0 v1.3.0 v1.4.0


Hence the question: what am I missing? Is there a special trick to inform the toolchain about the new major version that I am supposed to know?
P.S. Trying to force install via GONOPROXY also doesn't help:

The module documentation says

If the module is released at major version 2 or higher, the module path must end with a major version suffix like /v2. This may or may not be part of the subdirectory name.

Edit the module path in go.mod to include the /v2 suffix.
Use go install github.com/abelikoff/vidsim/v2@latest to install the command,.
